# Expanding values in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I currently have a matrix with the following values:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1]]
```

I would like to expand the values of 1 above and below by 1 resulting in an matrix like:

```
[[0,0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0],
 [1,1,1,1,0],
 [1,1,0,1,1],
 [0,0,0,1,1]]
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: The issue is the matrix in question is actually an image roughly 1000x750 pixels and the values of 1 are a line across the image. I want to create a buffer above and below this line in order to create a mask to select pixels by. I am really at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: _The issue is the matrix in question is actually an image roughly 1000x750 pixels and the values of 1 are a line across the image. I want to create a buffer above and below this line in order to create a mask to select pixels by._ Ah, why not ask about that, then?

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty row above and below, and then just add the array twice: shifted up one row and shifted down one row.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,1,0,0],
             [1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,1,0],
             [0,0,0,0,1]])

space = np.zeros((1,a.shape[1]),dtype=int)
c = np.vstack((space,a,space))
c[:a.shape[0]] += a
c[-a.shape[0]:]+= a
c = (c[1:-1]!=0).astype(int)
print(c)
```

Out:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]]
```